# Question about logical form of a statement

Tags: logic

Consider the following statement:

> Jane saw a police officer, and Roger saw one too.

Logical form of the statement above (provided by the book):
$$\exists x\big(P(x) \land S( j, x)\big) \land \exists y\big(P(y) \land S(r, y)\big)$$

Where $P(x)$ stands for “$x$ is a police officer”, $S(x, y)$ stands for “$x$ saw $y$”, $j$ stands for Jane, and $r$ stands for Roger.

Question is, assume I want to clearly show that the police officer that Roger saw **was not the one** that Jane saw, how do I do it?

Comment: What if there were two police officers and each of Roger and Jane saw both? Do you want your formula to be true then?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, both of them must only encounter one police officer, and the police officer that Roger came across is not the one that Jane saw

Comment: Then you need additional conditions on top of ArsenBerk's proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$\exists x\big(P(x) \land S( j, x) \big) \land \exists y\big(P(y) \land S(r, y) \land \lnot S(j,y)\big)$$

So, Jane didn't see $y$ but Roger did. So if we take both $x$ and $y$ to be the same, we have 
$$P(a) \land S(j,a) \land P(a) \land S(r,a) \land \lnot S(j,a)$$
which is a contradiction ($S(j,a) \land \lnot S(j,a)$).

Comment: But $S(r,x)$ is allowed? That's a curious asymmetry.

Comment: Actually my answer before editing was $\exists x\big(P(x) \land S(j, x) \land \lnot S(r,x) \big) \land \exists y\big(P(y) \land S(r, y) \land \lnot S(j,y)\big)$. Then I thought without $\lnot S(r,x)$, it also gives the same answer (by putting the same value into $x$ and $y$). Do we need the symmetry here?

Comment: There's an asymmetry of effect. If there's a policeman that both saw and another policeman seen by only Roger, then your formula is true. But if there's a policeman that both saw and another policeman seen by only _Jane_, then your formula is false.